# UINavigationController initiWithNibName not loading the design from the .xib file

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, interface-builder

In app delegate, inside didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function, I have the following code to load a view that is a UINavigationController:

```
 UINavigationController *navcon=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ThirdView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
```

`FirstView *fv=[[FirstView alloc] init];`

```
[navcon pushViewController:fv animated:NO];

[fv release];


[self.window addSubview:navcon.view];


[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

The .xib "ThirdView", that is a UINavigationController View, actually looks like this in the Interface Builder:

[image]

But when I run the app, the app looks like this:

[image]

Why is the application not loading the Navigation Bar design of "ThirdView.xib" UINavigationController as I have designed it in the Interface Builder?

Update: Here is how "FirstView" looks like in IB:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that what you are trying to do is valid. UINavigationController is intended to be a container for other views. You create the UINavigationController and then add your content to it by pushing view controllers onto it with pushViewController:animated:. It is the pushed view controllers that are created with .xib files.

Comment: Not sure why you were down voted, you are perfectly correct. What he is doing in incorrect. You cannot have a custom navigation controller in a XIB

Answer (score -1):

Each UIViewController in a Navigation controller is responsible for providing content to be display on the navigation bar.

In your view didLoad method of your FirstView do the following

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"your title";
```

But can you also post how your FirstView look in IB?

---

Personally I never setup the navigation bar in IB.
Here how you can set 2 button in code for your Navigation bar

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
[addButton release];
```

This code come from a UITableViewController subclass.

Comment: I know how to setup a navigation programatically, I actually want to know how can I see the one I made in the interface builder.

Comment: in your xib set the xib for the view in the inspector. Or set the view programatically, but don't push a view controller, it will take control of what is display on the navigation bar.